# How To Add Movement Sway To My Unity Game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am polishing up my very first game and I am trying to add a sway feature to my space ship that when moving left it rotates left and smoothly rotates back right when moving right. The ship can only move horizontally.[Static Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3238.png)

The ship can only move back and forth along the bottom but I want it to seem smoother but like swaying (a.k.a slightly pointing in the direction i want to go).

Sorry if this is a silly question or if not enough is included this is my first question on stack and first game. :)

I have tried making my own functions and stuff, but I seem to break it every time and have just been sticking to pure static horizontal movement.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DR4fTllQnXg

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following (you may you have to interchange the Euler vector according to your implementation):

```
currentRotation = Lerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * swaySpeed);
spaceship.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, currentRotation);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need three rotations (at least as far as I understand what you want to achieve). "middle" - your current default one, "max left" and "max right" to prevent infinite rotation.
2. Make your current rotation tend to middle value by default
3. Change your current "target" rotation depending on your input.

Here is [showcase](https://i.imgur.com/Vtbu1c6.mp4) and logic (this script is attached to the object with the plane)

```cs
...
    void Update()
    {
        Quaternion currentTarget = _defaultRotation;
        Vector3 currentMoveVector = _moveVectorDefault;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) == true)
        {
            currentTarget = _maxLeftRotation;
            currentMoveVector = _moveVectorLeft;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) == true)
        {
            currentTarget = _maxRightRotation;
            currentMoveVector = _moveVectorRight;
        }

        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, currentTarget, Time.deltaTime * _rotationSpeed);
        this.transform.position += currentMoveVector * (_moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
...
```